# How do I flat a Nested Json file in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a nested Json file with arrays.
I want to flat it so there won't be nested Jsons.

For example:

[image]

Code for Json:
https://jsonblob.com/4b255e51-7e9f-11e8-b89c-37203846213e

This Json has sub-Json and also array that contains Json.

The source is:

[image]

Output should be:

[image]

If there are arrays that contains a single Json they can be ignored. But if they have also sub-json they should be treated as above. Basically from my point of view each array is like a separated Json file.

I know that flating the Json can be done as:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
json_normalize(sample_object)
```

But this won't work with arrays.

Any idea how to make this work?

**EDIT:**

This is how arrays should be handled:
source:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Which means first Json in array stays as is {0}, {1} etc... but the sub-jsons are flatted.  There are **no** columns of `attributes_0_value`  !  Basically convert it to array with a single Json. No nesting (unless there is another array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10):

```
import pandas as pd
import json

response = {u'total': 1245, u'limit': 2, u'results': [{u'customer': {u'lastName': u'rtyrtyrt', u'userAccountId': None, u'id': 637, u'firstName': u'rtyrtyrty', u'email': u'ddfgdfg@dfsdfgdfg.ggg'}, u'shippingAddress': {u'city': u'rtyrtyrtyrty', u'vatNumber': None, u'firstName': u'rtyrtyrty', u'companyName': None, u'country': {u'defaultCulture': {u'languageName': u'English', u'code': u'en-GB', u'id': 2, u'name': u'English'}, u'onlineStoreActive': True, u'currency': {u'symbol': u'\xa3', u'code': u'GBP', u'id': 2, u'currencyCulture': u'en-GB', u'numericCode': 826}, u'locale': None, u'isO2LetterCode': u'GB', u'vatPercentage': 20.0, u'continent': u'Europe ', u'isoNumericCode': u'826', u'invariantName': u'UNITED KINGDOM', u'id': 2, u'isO3LetterCode': u'GBR'}, u'stateProvince': None, u'lastName': u'rtyrtyrt', u'zipCode': u'5464556', u'email': u'ddfgdfg@dfsdfgdfg.ggg', u'addressLine2': None, u'addressLine1': u'tyrtyrty', u'phoneNumber': u'45644443456456546', u'addressName': None, u'id': 861}, u'orderDateUtc': u'0001-01-01 00:00', u'shoppingCardId': 0, u'paymentType': {u'code': u'SafeCharge', u'invariantName': u'Credit Card', u'id': 50}, u'orderNumber': u'0100000845', u'giftMessage': u'', u'storeId': 1, u'shippingService': {u'deletedOn': None, u'code': u'ROYALSTD', u'courier': None, u'updatedOn': u'2018-01-24 09:23', u'locale': None, u'createdOn': u'2018-01-24 09:23', u'storeId': 1, u'sortOrder': 1, u'invariantName': u'Royal Mail Standard', u'id': 1}, u'referenceOrderNumber': u'', u'totals': {u'shippingChargesNet': 3.95, u'orderLevelDiscount': 0.0, u'grandTotal': 8.95, u'vatPercentage': 20.0, u'shippingChargesDiscount': 0.0, u'shippingCharges': 3.95, u'units': 1, u'salesTaxPerc': 0.0, u'subTotal': 5.0, u'salesTax': 1.4916666666666667}, u'currency': {u'symbol': u'\xa3', u'code': u'GBP', u'id': 2, u'currencyCulture': u'en-GB', u'numericCode': 826}, u'status': {u'invariantName': u'Waiting PackingList', u'id': 4, u'name': None}, u'billingAddress': {u'city': u'rtyrtyrtyrty', u'vatNumber': None, u'firstName': u'rtyrtyrty', u'companyName': None, u'country': {u'defaultCulture': {u'languageName': u'English', u'code': u'en-GB', u'id': 2, u'name': u'English'}, u'onlineStoreActive': True, u'currency': {u'symbol': u'\xa3', u'code': u'GBP', u'id': 2, u'currencyCulture': u'en-GB', u'numericCode': 826}, u'locale': None, u'isO2LetterCode': u'GB', u'vatPercentage': 20.0, u'continent': u'Europe ', u'isoNumericCode': u'826', u'invariantName': u'UNITED KINGDOM', u'id': 2, u'isO3LetterCode': u'GBR'}, u'stateProvince': None, u'lastName': u'rtyrtyrt', u'zipCode': u'5464556', u'email': u'ddfgdfg@dfsdfgdfg.ggg', u'addressLine2': None, u'addressLine1': u'tyrtyrty', u'phoneNumber': u'456456456546', u'addressName': None, u'id': 861}, u'items': [{u'orderId': 844, u'discountEach': 0.0, u'cancellationId': 0, u'orderedQty': 1, u'giftMessage': u'', u'orderLevelDiscountEach': 0.0, u'historicalCategories': [], u'giftFrom': u'', u'netShippingChargesEach': 3.95, u'promotionItemIds': [], u'variantId': 11282, u'attributes': [{u'value': u'', u'key': u'ProductSeason'}], u'priceEach': 5.0, u'isGift': False, u'id': 939, u'giftTo': u''}], u'attributes': [{u'value': u'2', u'key': u'CustomerCultureId'}, {u'value': u'185.13.248.67', u'key': u'IpAddress'}, {u'value': u'UA', u'key': u'IpCountryCode'}, {u'value': u'OLS', u'key': u'OrderSource'}, {u'value': u'111790', u'key': u'SafeCharge_AuthCode'}, {u'value': u'UQBzAGQAaAB3ADgAMgB0AE4AagBHADUAegBpAHMAIwA7AC4ANgA3AFEAXwBMAGAAKwAqAHIAVgBGAEcAKQBFAD0ASQA8AC4ATgA0AD8ANQA+AFAAMwA=', u'key': u'SafeCharge_Token'}, {u'value': u'1512424599', u'key': u'SafeCharge_TransactionId'}, {u'value': u'1', u'key': u'StoreId'}], u'isGift': False, u'id': 844}, {u'customer': {u'lastName': u'dfgdfg', u'userAccountId': None, u'id': 638, u'firstName': u'dfgdfg', u'email': u'hfghfgh@dfdfg.fdg'}, u'shippingAddress': {u'city': u'fghfghhf', u'vatNumber': None, u'firstName': u'dfgdfg', u'companyName': None, u'country': {u'defaultCulture': {u'languageName': u'English', u'code': u'en-GB', u'id': 2, u'name': u'English'}, u'onlineStoreActive': True, u'currency': {u'symbol': u'\xa3', u'code': u'GBP', u'id': 2, u'currencyCulture': u'en-GB', u'numericCode': 826}, u'locale': None, u'isO2LetterCode': u'GB', u'vatPercentage': 20.0, u'continent': u'Europe ', u'isoNumericCode': u'826', u'invariantName': u'UNITED KINGDOM', u'id': 2, u'isO3LetterCode': u'GBR'}, u'stateProvince': None, u'lastName': u'dfgdfg', u'zipCode': u'4564566', u'email': u'hfghfgh@dfdfg.fdg', u'addressLine2': None, u'addressLine1': u'fghfghfgh', u'phoneNumber': u'567567567', u'addressName': None, u'id': 862}, u'orderDateUtc': u'0001-01-01 00:00', u'shoppingCardId': 0, u'paymentType': {u'code': u'SafeCharge', u'invariantName': u'Credit Card', u'id': 50}, u'orderNumber': u'0100000846', u'giftMessage': u'', u'storeId': 1, u'shippingService': {u'deletedOn': None, u'code': u'ROYALSTD', u'courier': None, u'updatedOn': u'2018-01-24 09:23', u'locale': None, u'createdOn': u'2018-01-24 09:23', u'storeId': 1, u'sortOrder': 1, u'invariantName': u'Royal Mail Standard', u'id': 1}, u'referenceOrderNumber': u'', u'totals': {u'shippingChargesNet': 3.95, u'orderLevelDiscount': 0.0, u'grandTotal': 8.95, u'vatPercentage': 20.0, u'shippingChargesDiscount': 0.0, u'shippingCharges': 3.95, u'units': 1, u'salesTaxPerc': 0.0, u'subTotal': 5.0, u'salesTax': 1.4916666666666667}, u'currency': {u'symbol': u'\xa3', u'code': u'GBP', u'id': 2, u'currencyCulture': u'en-GB', u'numericCode': 826}, u'status': {u'invariantName': u'Shipped', u'id': 6, u'name': None}, u'billingAddress': {u'city': u'fghfghhf', u'vatNumber': None, u'firstName': u'dfgdfg', u'companyName': None, u'country': {u'defaultCulture': {u'languageName': u'English', u'code': u'en-GB', u'id': 2, u'name': u'English'}, u'onlineStoreActive': True, u'currency': {u'symbol': u'\xa3', u'code': u'GBP', u'id': 2, u'currencyCulture': u'en-GB', u'numericCode': 826}, u'locale': None, u'isO2LetterCode': u'GB', u'vatPercentage': 20.0, u'continent': u'Europe ', u'isoNumericCode': u'826', u'invariantName': u'UNITED KINGDOM', u'id': 2, u'isO3LetterCode': u'GBR'}, u'stateProvince': None, u'lastName': u'dfgdfg', u'zipCode': u'4563334566', u'email': u'hfghfgh@dfdfg.fdg', u'addressLine2': None, u'addressLine1': u'fghfghfgh', u'phoneNumber': u'567567567', u'addressName': None, u'id': 862}, u'items': [{u'orderId': 845, u'discountEach': 0.0, u'cancellationId': 0, u'orderedQty': 1, u'giftMessage': u'', u'orderLevelDiscountEach': 0.0, u'historicalCategories': [], u'giftFrom': u'', u'netShippingChargesEach': 3.95, u'promotionItemIds': [], u'variantId': 11282, u'attributes': [{u'value': u'', u'key': u'ProductSeason'}], u'priceEach': 5.0, u'isGift': False, u'id': 940, u'giftTo': u''}], u'attributes': [{u'value': u'2', u'key': u'CustomerCultureId'}, {u'value': u'115.11.118.67', u'key': u'IpAddress'}, {u'value': u'UA', u'key': u'IpCountryCode'}, {u'value': u'OLS', u'key': u'OrderSource'}, {u'value': u'111335', u'key': u'SafeCharge_AuthCode'}, {u'value': u'UQA1AEYASgBVAEgAcgBvAE8AWAAlAFMAaABcAGAAMwA0AG4ATABiAHAAcQBoAEkAawB6AHMANQBXAEgAUQApACQATwBpAEQAUABAAGcAKwBcADQAMwA=', u'key': u'SafeCharge_Token'}, {u'value': u'1512424624', u'key': u'SafeCharge_TransactionId'}], u'isGift': False, u'id': 845}], u'offset': 0}

sample_object = pd.DataFrame(response)['results'].to_dict()    

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out


flat = {k: flatten_json(v) for k, v in sample_object.items()}

with open('flat.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    jsonfile.write(json.dumps(flat))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174342/discussion-on-answer-by-ashish-acharya-how-do-i-flat-a-nested-json-file-in-pytho).

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this procedure.

**First store the JSON data as string** (or, load from url or file)

[image]

**use *nested_to_record()* method from pandas**

```
import json
from pandas.io.json.normalize import nested_to_record    

json_dic = json.loads(json_str)
flat = nested_to_record(json_dic, sep='_')

for key in flat:
    print key, flat[key]
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer my question. You embedded the row number in the column names... you removed all Jsons - this is not what I was referring to... See my examples in the post.